# Is PHP curl to HTTPS secure?

Tags: php, http, curl, https

I read these two things:

- Sending data from HTTP to HTTPS is not safe.
- Curl is as secure as a normal HTTP request.

Putting these together, would sending a password to an HTTPS server through curl be insecure? Do both servers need HTTPS in order to be secure?

Comment: Well technically no, but its better. Remember a CURL request comes from the server not the clients computer so unless your server or your network is compromised you should be fine. Unless their server is specifically set up to only allow HTTPS requests

Comment: The second line should read as `Curl sending an HTTP request is as secure as any other HTTP request.` But curl can also send a https request.

Answer (score 3):

Using curl in php **is** safe **as long as you don't disabled the certificate verification**.

Do **not** touch CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST and CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, their default values are the secure ones.

https://secure.php.net/manual/fr/function.curl-setopt.php